# What is the negation of the definition that a metric space is complete?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, what is the negation of the definition that $(X, d)$ is complete?

I know a metric space is complete if every Cauchy sequence is convergent. I got really confused now.

Comment: So, it is not complete if there is some Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1):

$(X,d)$ is not complete $ \iff$ there is a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ and no $x \in X$ such that $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: Let me take a look! Thanks!